# Visual Studio 2015 System.Exception Package could not be registered.error 0x80070005 Xaml issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just started reading Head First C# and was about to start the first app to work on when I received the following error... I'm honestly not sure what to do to fix it. Any suggestions?'

```
System.Exception Package could not be registered.
error 0x80070005: While processing the request, the system failed to register the windows.capability extension due to the following error: Access is denied. . at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, PlatformIdentifier platformIdentifier, String identifier, String baseDirectory) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass41.<StartTask>b__5() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: Also getting the same problem - be interested to know what's causing this myself...

Comment: Hey guys, if you are following the tutorials on the Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN) (Which I am following as well) their appears to be an issue in the tutorial that does not relate correctly to either VC 2015 or Windows 10 :(

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error and went to settings > update and security > for developers and enabled developer mode, worked for me good luck.